# no error message in CMD after uninstalling python3.2

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-2.6

Hi I am  running in windows XP. I have python2.6 and python 3.2 installed at the same time.

My problem is when i uninstall python 3.2 and run a program with an error, the CMD does not return error message. But the program execute properly when it has no error.

I've tried re installing python2.6 but it is still the same.

Comment: There is not close to enough information in your question for anyone to help you. Show us example code, the exact way you ran it, the error you were expecting, what output you got, etc.

Comment: The cmd does not respond to error or print. I've created a test.py with the code of print 'test', when i run it directly in python idle it return 'test' but when i run it using CMD or double click test.py icon nothing happens

Comment: If you run "python test.py" or if you just run "test.py"? Try "python test.py" and post what happens.

Comment: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. But when i paste it in C:\Python26 and run python test.py it works. How can i run my .py even if is not in C:\Python26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
2. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
3. In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
4. In the Environment Variables window highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button.
5. Each directory is separated by a semi-colon. Add "C:\Python26" to the end (making sure it has a semi-colon before it).

Now you should be able to type "python test.py" from anywhere and it will work.

Comment: thank you very much agf it solves my problem, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix the registry settings, so double-clicking a .py file will work:

Go into control panel, choose Add/Remove Programs.  Find Python 2.6 and choose the option to repair it.  Test to see if that fixed the problem.

If it still doesn't work, then: Go into control panel, choose Add/Remove Programs.  Find Python 2.6 and choose the option to Change installed features.  Choose to install the "Register as default Python" feature.